# calculate the start and the end position of a protein group from a dictionary in python

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I am using python to analyze and edit some information I have from a database of proteins.
Having a dictionary with this output :

```
NC_018142.1_1102_ID=1_1102  (**1277003**, 1279534, 4, 'CAS-II-C 0.64')
NC_018142.1_1103_ID=1_1103  (1279648, 1280793, 4, 'CAS-II-C 0.64')
NC_018142.1_1104_ID=1_1104  (1280954, 1282252, 4, 'CAS-II-C 0.64')
NC_018142.1_1458_ID=1_1458  (1650240, 1651379, 4, 'CAS-II-C 0.64')
NC_018142.1_1459_ID=1_1459  (1651731, 1651955, 4, 'CAS-II-C 0.64')
NC_018142.1_1460_ID=1_1460  (1651976, 1652779, 4, 'CAS-II-C 0.64')
NC_018142.1_1461_ID=1_1461  (1652848, **1653054**, 4, 'CAS-II-C 0.64')

NC_018142.1_1906_ID=1_1906  (**2167100**, 2169223, 5, 'CAS-III-D 0.61')
NC_018142.1_1907_ID=1_1907  (2169220, 2171208, 5, 'CAS-III-D 0.61')
NC_018142.1_1908_ID=1_1908  (2171205, **2172977**, 5, 'CAS-III-D 0.61')
```

where the keys show a protein id, the fist column from the value shows the start in the dna string, the second shows the end, the third shows the group of protein's number and the last column shows a type of immune system.
what I am trying to do is to get an output like :

```
NC_018142  (1277003, 1653054, 4, 'CAS-II-C 0.64')
NC_018142  (2171205, 2172977, 5, 'CAS-III-D 0.61')
```

the start is the start in dna string and the end is the last position in the string regarding the protein group. so the start is the start from the first row and end is the end from the last row regarding the protein group. protein group 4 would have start : 1277003 and end : 1653054.
Can someone please give me any idea and help me how can I do this? 
Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't protein group 5 have start : 2167100?

Comment: yes and end : 2172977. I have mistakenly written 2171205

Comment: Also dictionary keys need to be unique. so you cannot have such a dictionary. Would a pandas dataframe be ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, and if its what you are looking for let me know so i can comment on what each line is doing

```
import pandas as pd

d ={'NC_018142.1_1102_ID=1_1102':('**1277003**', 1279534, 4, 'CAS-II-C 0.64'),
'NC_018142.1_1103_ID=1_1103':(1279648, 1280793, 4, 'CAS-II-C 0.64'),
'NC_018142.1_1104_ID=1_1104':(1280954, 1282252, 4, 'CAS-II-C 0.64'),
'NC_018142.1_1458_ID=1_1458':(1650240, 1651379, 4, 'CAS-II-C 0.64'),
'NC_018142.1_1459_ID=1_1459':(1651731, 1651955, 4, 'CAS-II-C 0.64'),
'NC_018142.1_1460_ID=1_1460':(1651976, 1652779, 4, 'CAS-II-C 0.64'),
'NC_018142.1_1461_ID=1_1461':(1652848, '**1653054**', 4, 'CAS-II-C 0.64'),

'NC_018142.1_1906_ID=1_1906':('**2167100**', 2169223, 5, 'CAS-III-D 0.61'),
'NC_018142.1_1907_ID=1_1907':(2169220, 2171208, 5, 'CAS-III-D 0.61'),
'NC_018142.1_1908_ID=1_1908':(2171205, '**2172977**', 5, 'CAS-III-D 0.61')
}


df = pd.DataFrame(d).T.reset_index()
col_names = ['proteinID', 'start', 'end', 'group', 'type']
df.columns = col_names
df['proteinID'] = df['proteinID'].str.split('.').str[0]
df['start'] = df['start'].astype(str).str.replace('*', '')
df['end'] = df['end'].astype(str).str.replace('*', '')

df = df.groupby(['proteinID', 'group']).agg({'start':'first', 'end':'last','type':'first'}).reset_index()

df = df[col_names]
df
```

The end result will be a pandas dataframe:

```
    proteinID   start   end     group   type
0   NC_018142   1277003 1653054   4     CAS-II-C 0.64
1   NC_018142   2167100 2172977   5     CAS-III-D 0.61
```

Comment: thank you! I have a question ; how can I transform a dictionary in a panda dataframe? because everything is in a dictionary :(

Comment: i have in the answer
`df = pd.DataFrame(d)` assuming `d` is your dictionary

Comment: oh, than it will be perfect! let me try!

Comment: "values have {new} elements".format(old=old_len, new=new_len)
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4 elements, new values have 5 elements

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste your dictionary.its easier for us to test out

Comment: ```
NC_018142.1_1102_ID=1_1102  (**1277003**, 1279534, 4, 'CAS-II-C 0.64')
NC_018142.1_1103_ID=1_1103  (1279648, 1280793, 4, 'CAS-II-C 0.64')
NC_018142.1_1104_ID=1_1104  (1280954, 1282252, 4, 'CAS-II-C 0.64')
NC_018142.1_1458_ID=1_1458  (1650240, 1651379, 4, 'CAS-II-C 0.64')
NC_018142.1_1461_ID=1_1461  (1652848, **1653054**, 4, 'CAS-II-C 0.64')

NC_018142.1_1906_ID=1_1906  (**2167100**, 2169223, 5, 'CAS-III-D 0.61')
NC_018142.1_1907_ID=1_1907  (2169220, 2171208, 5, 'CAS-III-D 0.61')
NC_018142.1_1908_ID=1_1908  (2171205, **2172977**, 5, 'CAS-III-D 0.61')

```

Comment: this is the dictionary, the key is in this form : NC_018142.1_1102_ID=1_1102  and the values are inside the brackets

Comment: thats not a dictionary its a string. ill have a look at it in a bit

Comment: thank you, I fixed! the problem was that 'type' was not added to the dictionary, just printed!

Comment: maybe by chance you know how can I store this dataframe in a .tab extension file? xp

Comment: `df.to_csv('somename.csv', sep='\t')`

Comment: I have already tried this but I think it takes by default only the data from 1 kind of protein, not for all of them

Comment: Is everything you need in one dataframe?

Comment: each df dataframe like you suggested that will be generated for different proteins need to be printed/ stored in a .tab extension file. I tried df.to_csv('outputFinal.csv',sep='\t')but it gives me the result only for the last protein. I tried also this method : with open('outputFinal.tab','w') as o:
                o.write(df.to_string())

Comment: in both cases I got result printed only for the last protein, not for all of them. I dont know but I think this issue might be connected to  reset.index() . I tried removing it but I get an error afterwards..